# Unable to print PDF correctly

Tags: printing, pdf, evince, brother

When I try to print a PDF, it prints, but the first page has weird symbols replacing some of the letters (notice that the symbols look similar to the letters that should be there):

[image: Picture of first page]

The second page is blank, except for this error message:

```
ERROR:
undefined
OFFENDING COMMAND:
....Undefined
STACK:
0
0
431
431
683
0
0
0
-194
0
0
0
0
0
0
-195
0
0
0
0
0
0
268
0
0
0
-mark-
-mark-
-mark-
```

My printer is a Brother HL-5150D. I can print documents from LibreOffice just fine. The document had 5 pages, was generated by LaTeX, and was printed using the standard Document Viewer (Evince).

**How can I fix the printer so it can print PDFs? Will a different printer driver or document viewer work?**

***EDIT:*** I've been able to print my document correctly with the Ocular document viewer (see [my own answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/250061/109543)), but I still would like to be able to print it using the standard Evince document viewer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried printing using the KDE document viewer Okular, and the document printed perfectly correct, no weird characters or undefined stack errors! So it seems to be a problem with the Evince document viewer.

Comment: I have had similar problems with printing (not viewing) from the built-in firefox viewer (firefox 43).  Okular worked correctly for me as well.

Comment: didn't work for me, error also in okular.